# How to check for a necessary input of raw_input?

Tags: python, input

I've started to learn python only a day ago, seems to be easy, but still have some questions :)

how to write a script which have to check necessary input of raw_input?

I mean, the script must stop if a user have not entered any case and just hit enter on raw_input...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ans = raw_input('Enter: ')
if not ans:
    print "You entered nothing!"
else:
    print "You entered something!"
```

If the user hits enter, `ans` will be `''`. and `''` is considered `False`, thus as the condition is `True` (`not False`), the if block will run.

If you wish to continually ask the user for an input, you can use a while-loop:

```
ans = ''
while not ans: # While the input given is an empty string
    ans = raw_input('Enter: ')
```

Comment: Just <ENTER> evaluates to `'\n'`, whose `bool` is `True`. This script does not meet the spec

Comment: @inspectorG4dget No, it doesn't evaluate to that.

Comment: Try running it on an interpreter. I just did

Comment: Me too: http://pastie.org/8155585

Comment: @inspectorG4dget from the docs: The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (**stripping a trailing newline**), and returns that

Comment: Sorry folks! I just checked out my environment and realized I had overloaded some stuff, which was leading me to the erroneous conclusion (how emabrassing!). I withdraw my objections

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Lol ;)

Comment: @user2597220 Glad to hear :D!

Answer (score 3):

[raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) return empty string (`''`) if user just hit enter.

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
>   converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
>   that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

```
if raw_input() == '':
    break # or return
```

---

```
if not raw_input():
    break # or return
```

Comment: An <ENTER> without any text evaluates to `'\n'`, which is not `''`, nor is `bool('\n')` `False`. This will not work

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, You are wrong. raw_input() return empty string on enter.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, I added a link to raw_input() documentation.

Comment: Sorry! I just checked out my environment and realized I had overloaded some stuff, which was leading me to the erroneous conclusion (how emabrassing!). I withdraw my objections